# Calculate p-value?

Tags: p-value, odds-ratio

I have calculated the OR by hand to be 5.85 and I want to evaluate the support in the data for a link between alcohol use and esophageal cancer by calculating a p-value and interpret it. How do I do that?

Comment: Chi-square test for independence?

Comment: @StatisticsRat I had gone through the entering of data, etc in R by the time your comment popped up, so I just went ahead with the answer. I figured I was helping a fellow in the medical field. BTW, if user153200 got the answer, can you click on "accept"? Ty

Comment: @Antoni Parellada Don't worry. I was just too lazy for a more sophisticated answer. Glad you took the job. ;)

Comment: Can I ask you why you un-accepted my answer? It is correct. Was there anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected counts in each cell are $>5$, allowing you to use a chi square test of independence. I use the Fisher test to get the OR.

```
> m=matrix(c(386,29,389,171),nrow=2)
> dimnames(m)=list(cancer=c("yes","no"),alcohol=c("<40 g/day",">40 g/day"))
> addmargins(m)
      alcohol
cancer <40 g/day >40 g/day Sum
   yes       386       389 775
   no         29       171 200
   Sum       415       560 975
> chisq.test(m)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  m
X-squared = 79.623, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16

> fisher.test(m)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  m
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.814237 9.212062
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  5.841632
```